# Lua: how to do the regex `(.{1,32})`?

Tags: lua

I am writing my thesis and I use LuaLaTeX to have a feature like: `variable` and then have it in another font (like you see here on SO). There are all kinds of gotcha's and I basically decided I just want to hack it.

However, I can't seem to find to do the alternative of the above regex, because I don't know how to count characters.

So does anyone know how to do this? I am not too familiar with Lua (and it's tough debugging it in a LaTeX environment) and Googling doesn't give me an answer.

Comment: Is there a strong reason you need to cap it at 32 characters? ie, can you explain why `(.+)` won't work?

Comment: `.{1,32}` is equivalent to `..?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?`, but the latter is absolutely impractical due to huge amount of time needed for backtracking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lua doesn't support this feature in its pattern matching engine. You'll have to change it to `(.+)` and then check for the length to be 32 or less or use [lpeg library](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/).